# Javascript replace all in array with in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array with .gif, .png, etc in it. And I want to replace with with @2.gif, @2.png,etc respectively.

Example

```
.gif -> @2.gif
.png -> @2.png
```

I tried doing string.replace, but I can't specific an array with replace with.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace using regular expressions:

```
str = str.replace(/\.(gif|png)/gi, '@2.$1');
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/hafEM/) Also, depending on what exactly you're replacing, you may not need the `g` flag (which specifies that all instances of the pattern should be replaced, as opposed to simply the first found.)

Comment: @NiklasB.: How so? (See demo.)

Comment: The extensions are stored in an array, so you should map a regex escape function over it and join using `|`.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Ah, sorry, that's not what I got out of the question :P I'll add that. Just let me find my regex-escaping function :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<MyArray.length;i++)
{
  MyArray[i]="@2"+MyArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
 '.gif',
 '.png'
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 arr[i] = '@2' + arr[i];
 alert(arr[i]); 
}

// @2.gif and @2.png are printed out
```

Answer (score 0):

Why string replace?  Just iterate over the array and map the values.

```
arrayOfImages = arrayOfImages.map(function(val, i) {
     return '@' + i + val;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hWqEe/

Answer (score 0):

**Crazy alternative:**

```
var arr = ["gif", "png", "jpg"];

arr = ("@2" + arr.join("*@2.")).split("*");
```

**Note:** just make sure you use have any `*` char inside any item of the array, if you want to use it, just use another improbable character

Answer (score -1):

Just use +

Like for eg

var='@2'+var

If you want to be aplied to all elements put this im the loop.